# Email the contents of a plist

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, email

Is it possible to email the contents of a plist without opening up the mail app? Could this be something done with some PHP on a server? I have been researching this idea for a little bit now, and seem to keep ending up at the tutorials where the app will open up the mail program and attached the plist that way. Just wanted to see if there were other options.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can send the data to a server and have PHP send the e-mail.

Comment: Know of any examples that do this?

Comment: `NSURLConnection` to send to the server. `mail` function in php. Try something and come back with specific problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and yes. A plist is just a file. You can use the MFMailComposeViewController to display a compose email inside your app, and pre-fill out the recipient, body, subject, and the attached file.

It is NOT possible to send email without user interaction. That is Apple's design.

As the other poster said, you can send the file to a server and have a PHP script on the server send the email.